# Bitmap image is not decoding the json image url in the image view

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-bitmap

Hi i have been trying to decode the image url from the json file. The image is placed in the assets folder and the image name is given in the json file under the name:

> offlineImageUri : "startachannel.jpg"

The function to load bitmap image from the assets is as follow:

```
    public Bitmap loadBitmapFromAssets(Context context, String path) {
        InputStream stream = null;
        try {
            stream = context.getAssets().open(path);
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        } finally {
            try {
                if (stream != null) {
                    stream.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Below is the code to show bitmap image in the **onResponse**. My network image view is loading the image from the server and it is working perfectly fine but when the user is offline the image view in the **onErrorResponse** is not displaying any image. I think the problem is when i'm decoding the bitmap image.

```
mImageLoader = Volley.getInstance(mContext).getImageLoader();
        mImageLoader.get(mUrl, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(mUrl, mImageLoader);
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Bitmap m = loadBitmapFromAssets(mContext, mMethod.contents.offlineImageUri);
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(m);
                mNetworkImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Below is the image view tag used in res layout.xml

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/offlineImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:visibility="gone"></ImageView>
```

Comment: `mMethod.contents.offlineImageUri`? What is that? And what is its value?

Comment: I wonder why you post that Volley code. Enough would have been the code where you try to set an imageview from assets.

Comment: `catch (Exception ignored) {`. Very bad coding. And even twice. If something happens you will never know. Add the normal code for a catch block and a toast to inform the user. And yourself.

Comment: @greenapps mMethod.contents.offlineImageUri is the json file object . offlineImageUri is the sub object of content object in json

Comment: You have not given the info i asked for. You did not react to suggestions.  And you just repeated what we already knew. If you continue in this way nobody can help you.

Comment: value for mMethod.contents.offlineImageUri is the list of images stored in the json e.g. for my first json object mMethod.contents.offlineImageUri values is "startachannel.jpg", same goes for the rest of ten objects in json file

Comment: You should of course supply only one file name to that function. Not a list of images. Well you will have an exception there now but if you refuse to handle those catches in a normal way as i suggested you will never know.